# Object literal property and method location

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties, object-literal

Do all methods have to be stated after all properties in JavaScript when defining objects in object literal form? I have tried voiding this idea and it seems that all properties stated afterwards are not included.

Comment: Something does not seem right. Show a code example that you base your conclusion on.

Comment: Perhaps you messed up your braces, sticking the subsequent properties into the function body.

Comment: Yes, I found my mistake. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do all methods have to be stated after all properties in JavaScript when defining objects in object literal form?

No.

Object properties have a value that is either a primitive or a reference to an object. The order in which they are added, either by a literal or assignment, is irrelevant:

```
var obj = {
  prop0: 0,
  method0: function(){},
  prop1: 1,
  method1: function(){}    
}
```